# file cmdline does not show script name anymore

Tags: bash

We have 2 linux servers, one is SLES 11 SP3, and the other is SLES 12 SP2.

In Sles 11 sp3, when you start a batch script (name "test.sh"), which has $PID 2200, you can go to

```
/proc/2200/cmdline
```

and you will see something like

```
/bin/shtest.sh
```

So you can get the script name here.

In Sles 12 sp2 when you do exactly the same thing, you will see only

```
-bash
```

It was good for me to have the name in it, so I could get the name of the parent script (with $PPID).

But now the scipt file name is not there anymore.

Is there any alternative now to get the name of the parent script?

Thanks alot in advance.

Edit:
On the new server (12 sp 2), the only place in /proc/"id", where I found 
the name was in "/proc/"id"/fd"

```
fstest:/proc/11248/fd # ls -l
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb  9 15:52 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb  9 15:52 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb  9 15:52 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Feb  9 15:52 254 -> /batch/test1.sh
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Feb  9 15:52 255 -> /dev/pts/3
```

But I don't know what I should make with it, what is "254"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

In "/proc/"id"/fd you have the file descriptors (see above).

0, 1, and 2 are always "in", "out" and "err" (don't not the order).

And it seems that 254 always links to the script.